# Laravel AJAX Delete route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Trabajo con Laravel 5.5
Tengo un problema con la variable "id" al colocar la ruta del AJAX. Les paso a mostrar

Route

```
Route::DELETE('deletePlan/{id}', 'FormDController@deletePlan')->name('d.deletePlan');
```

En el AJAX tengo lo siguiente (aclaro que el valor del "id" al AJAX llega bien, el error me surge al agregarlo a la ruta

```
$('.delete_plan').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var row = $(this).parents(".contenedor");
var li = e.target.parentNode;
var id= li.id;
var param = {
    'id'       : id,
    '_method'  : 'delete',
    '_token'   : '{{Session::token()}}'
};
ruta1 = "http://192.168.156.201/EMPRESA/intranet/administrator/d/deletePlan/" + id;
$.ajax({
    url: ruta1,
    type : 'post',
    data :   param,
    success: function( msg ) {
        row.fadeOut();
        alert("Registro borrado correctamente !!!");
    },
    error: function( data ) {
        alert("Ocurrió un error !!!");
    }
});

return false;
```

});

Así como está ruta1 funciona bien, obviamente lo puse para probar solamente, esto quiere decir que el resto esta todo bien, y en el controller también está todo bien. Ahora en lugar de esa url probe de distintas maneras poner el "router" como corresponde, y en algunos casos me tira que no conoce id, en otros casos me pasa al controller la PALABRA id y no su valor, etc no pude encontrar la manera de poner la "route" como corresponde.

```
"{{ route('d.deletePlan', "id") }}";

"{{ route('d.deletePlan', 'id') }}";

"{{ route('discapacidad.deletePlan') }}", + id;
```

Ninguna de estas formas me funciona, todos me ponen la url correspondiente pero la variable en el primer caso y en el segundo me pone la palabra "id" en vez de pònerme el número correspondiente. Y en la última opción me tira un error diciendo que falta el parámetro

Podrían ayudarme como se coloca la ruta? También probe de poner comillas simples las de afuera en vez de comillas doble. He probado varias opciones pero no logré hacer que funcione

Reitero, la ruta o sea la url la coloca bien, el tema es el parámetro, no logro formar la url, por ejemplo

```
"http://192.168.156.201/EMPRESA/intranet/administrator/d/deletePlan/5";
```

Answer (score 2):

Una solución práctica y sencilla, para no complicar el uso de `route()` con variables que posteriormente son agregadas por JavaScript, y teniendo en cuenta que el parámetro de la ruta es requerido, es utilizar un string como valor del "id" y luego reemplazarlo también desde JavaScript:

```
let id = li.id

let ruta1 = "{{ route('d.deletePlan', 'req_id') }}"

var ruta = ruta1.replace('req_id', id)

$.ajax({
    url: ruta,
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando el nombre de la ruta:

```
"{{ route('d.deletePlan') }}"+ "/" + id;
```

Tienes que poner la barra entre la ruta y el id porque si no lo haces estás poniendo una ruta incorrecta.