# asignar variable js a ruta laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, blade, routes

Tengo esta ruta

```
Route::delete('/Paciente/delete/{id}', [PacienteController::class,'delete'])->name('Paciente/delete')->middleware('auth');
```

El problema es que necesito llamarla dentro de una peticion `httpRequest`

```
const url = "/Paciente/delete/" + paciente_id;
```

Estoy usando esto.
Pero me gustaria usar el `{{route('Paciente/delete',['user'=>   AQUI IRIA EL VALOR DE Paciente_Id    ])}}`

El problema es que `paciente_id` es una variable de js.
Como lo asigno a la ruta?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Laravel AJAX Delete route](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/137312/laravel-ajax-delete-route)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer algo del estilo:

```
let url= '{{ route('Paciente/delete', ['user'=> :paciente_id ]) }}';
url = url.replace(':paciente_id', paciente_id);
```

Answer (score -1):

No puede pasar valores variables del código JavaScript al código PHP de la página. El código PHP se ejecuta en el lado del servidor y no sabe nada sobre lo que está sucediendo en el lado del cliente.